# hp-ux ps,what the difference between sleeping and waiting?

Tags: ps, hp-ux

On hpux

```
ps -efl
```

I see on output the letter S,which mean "state of process"
I see voices like S(sleeping) and W(waiting)
I know(hope is correct) Sleeping mean "waiting for event",but what does it mean Waiting?
My doubt is:

```
S=Sleeping OK
W=?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the book *HP-UX: HP Certified Systems Administrator 11i v3* by Asghar Ghori (paraphrased):

- the *running* state indicates the processor is currently being executed by a system CPU
- the *sleeping* state shows that the process is waiting for input
- the *waiting* state the process is ready to run as its turn arrives

...

In other words, in a system with just a single CPU core, only one process at a time can be in the Running state, and all the others that could possibly be Running are Waiting instead.

And because you'll need to run a process to get the process information, on a single-core system you may only ever see the process that is running the `ps` command or similar process information tool in the R state. Only on a system with 2 or more CPU cores you will be able to see other processes in the R state, while your process is running to get the process information.

So, in human timescales, the R and W states are actually essentially equivalent: between the time the process information is received from the kernel and the time a human has read the display on the screen and understood it, several of the processes in the W state may have had their turn on the processor (= in the R state) and returned to the W state to wait for another turn.

All the process states are "OK" in some situations. For example, even the Z state (Terminated, or "zombie") is OK unless a process stays in that state for a long time; if so, then it's a symptom of the *parent* process having some problem so that it cannot/will not read the exit code of its own child process.